# pset 6 scourgify fails two last check50 components

Tags: python, cs50

I am doing problem set 6 [scourgify](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/6/scourgify/). my code seems two all check50 components except the last two:

**:( scourgify.py cleans short csv file**

**:( scourgify.py cleans long csv file**

I don't know what I am missing.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import csv

# check for two command-line arguments
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    try:
    # creat a buffer csv file
        buffer = []
        #open input file for reading
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as file_input:
            # read input file
            reader = csv.reader(file_input)
            for row in reader:
                # append each line into a csv buffer
                buffer.append(row)

        # open output file for writing
        with open(sys.argv[2], "w") as file_output:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, fieldnames= ["first", "last", "house"])
            writer.writerow({"first": "first", "last": "last", "house": "house"})
            #ignore the first row of csv buffer
            for line in buffer[1:]:
                first, last = line[0].split(",")
                writer.writerow({"first": first, "last": last.lstrip(), "house": line[1]})



    except OSError:
        sys.exit(f"Couldn't read {sys.argv[1]}")




# check for fewer command-line arguments
elif len(sys.argv) < 3:
    sys.exit("Too few comman-line arguments")

# check for more command-line argument
else:
    sys.exit("Too many command-line arguments")
```

I thought my code should pass check50, unfortunately it can't clean short or long csv file. I don't know what that means. I have tried lstrip() but still get similar results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the spec:

> each “row” in the [input] file has three values (last name, first name, and house),

This program does not output the columns in the order defined in the spec:

> a new CSV to write as output, whose columns should be, in order, `first`, `last`, and `house`

Comment: Thank you. I see I forgot to switch positions of the names.

Answer (score 0):

I too was failing check50 with ":( scourgify.py cleans short CSV file" until removing a leading whitepsace before the first name.

Working after.csv:

```
first,last,house
Hannah,Abbott,Hufflepuff
```

Failing after.csv

```
first,last,house
 Hannah,Abbott,Hufflepuff
```